# Radius of the convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How to calculate the radius of the convergence of the series and what the result will be: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(3^n-2^n+2^{-n} \right) x^n$$
Is it enough to look for $\left( \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n| }\right)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes **it is sufficient** to evaluate
$$
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n| },
$$ here you may just write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
3^n-2^n+2^{-n}=3^n\left( 1-\left(\frac23\right)^n+\left(\frac16\right)^n\right)\sim 3^n
$$ then you deduce a radius of convergence equal to $\dfrac13$.

Comment: Why it is legal to get rid of the $x_n$ as you did?

Comment: @kurkowski Sorry, since we always have $\displaystyle \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|x^n| }=|x|$, I focussed on $3^n-2^n+2^{-n}$ ... Of course what I mean is that here we get $$
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n| }=3|x|
$$ and we want it to be $<1$. Thanks.

Comment: another question, why <1 ? I just want to fully understand this

Comment: Just to have the convergence, since in this case $\sum r^n$ will be convergent. You may have a look here :http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/calculus/intervals-of-convergence/intervals-of-convergence.html